# $\sqrt{\Delta} = $ the distance between the midpoint and the two roots

Tags: quadratics

I understand how the midpoint of a parabola is found when one of the roots is $0$ ( it is just $-b/2a$ )

but I can't understand why $\sqrt{\Delta} $ in the quadratic formula $=$ the distance between any of our real roots and our midpoint.

I want to know the proof behind this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you are interested in is the derivation of $\Delta$ and a justification for its role as the distance between the solutions I think this might be helpful.

Consider the quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \neq 0$. Then, one can factor the $a$ out to obtain $a(x^2 + \frac{b}{a}x) + c = 0$. Since $a \neq 0$ one can also divide both sides of the equation by $a$ to obtain $(x^2 + \frac{b}{a}x) + \frac{c}{a} = 0$. The first non trivial manipulation is the recognition that $(x^2 + \frac{b}{a}x)$ is fairly close to $(x + \frac{b}{2a})^2$. Indeed, there is only a term of $\frac{b^2}{4a^2}$ of difference. Therefore, one can write

\begin{align}
(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x) + \frac{c}{a} &= (x + \frac{b}{2a})^2 -\frac{b^2}{4a^2} + \frac{c}{a}.
\end{align}
Rearranging, one obtains
\begin{equation}
(x + \frac{b}{2a})^2 = \frac{b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2}.
\end{equation}
The numerator of the term on the right can be recognised as $\Delta$. Thus,
\begin{equation}
(x + \frac{b}{2a})^2 = \frac{\Delta}{4a^2}.
\end{equation}
The last step is to take square roots of both sides to find $x$ alone. However, we know that there are two real numbers such that their square equals $\Delta$ and that both these are solutoins. Thus, we find the usual quadratic formula
\begin{equation}
x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}.
\end{equation}
or more suggestively
\begin{equation}
x = \frac{-b}{2a} \pm \frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}.
\end{equation}
From this expression it is clear that the roots of the equations are going to be on either side of $\frac{-b}{2a}$ one being $\frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$ towards one side and the other being $\frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$ towards the other side of the vertex.

Answer (score 1):

If the roots are $r_1,r_2$, then the sum of the roots $r_1+r_2=\frac{-b}{a}$ and the product of the roots is $r_1r_2=\frac{c}{a}$.

The distance between the two (real) roots is given by $$|r_1-r_2|=\sqrt{(r_1+r_2)^2-4r_1r_2}.$$

The distance between the mid-point and either of the roots is $\frac{|r_1-r_2|}{2}$. Now you can fill in the details.

Comment: Sorry but isn't the sum of the roots -b/a?

Comment: @Shadowsparkle you are right. I will fix the typo.

Answer (score 1):

We know that a parabola is of the form $f(x) =ax^2+bx+c=0$. We can find the roots of the equation by using the quadratic formula:
$$
r_{1,2} = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}
$$
Suppose that a parabola $\mathscr{P}$ has two roots $r_1, r_2$ then the midpoint of the parabola is $x_1 = -\frac{b}{2a}$, which is also the axis of symmetry of the parabola. To see this, we rewrite the parabolaformula as:
$$
f(x) = a(x-e)^2 +k
$$
where $$
e = -\frac{b}{2c}, \:\:k= \frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}
$$
(you can check for yourself that these are equivalent). Now it is clear, from the square, that $f$ is symmetric around the point $e = -\frac{b}{2a}$.

Because of the symmetry, the distance from the roots to $x_{\text{1}}$ must be constant.

We are considering a parabola with two roots, thus $\Delta>0$. The roots are then:
$$
r_1 = \frac{-b + \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}, \:\: r_2 = \frac{-b - \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}
$$
so the distance from the midpoint $x_1$ to the roots is:
\begin{align*}
d_1 &= \left|x_1 - r_1 \right| = \left| - \frac{b}{2a} - \frac{-b + \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}\right| = \frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{2|a|} \\
d_2 &= \left| x_1 - r_2 \right| = \left| - \frac{b}{2a} - \frac{-b - \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a} \right| = \frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{2|a|}
\end{align*}
so the distance between the roots and the midpoint is, in both cases, equal to $\frac{\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$

Comment: Thank you so much